# Error when deploying .NET Core webapp to Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure

I am a complete beginner on the .NET world trying to get my first dummy .NET Core webapp to run on Azure App Service.

The code can be found here:
https://github.com/jordi-chacon/bcn_pollution

My development machine runs Ubuntu, so I am using Visual Studio Code.

I currently have my .NET Core webapp running on localhost:5000 just fine and now I want it to run on Azure App Service.

I have successfully configured Continuous Deployment on my App Service to fetch the code from Github.

Then Azure tried to deploy my webapp but it failed with the following error:

```
Using the following command to generate deployment script: 'azure site deploymentscript -y --no-dot-deployment -r "D:\home\site\repository" -o "D:\home\site\deployments\tools" --aspNet5 "D:\home\site\repository\project.json" --aspNet5Version "1.0.0-rc1-final" --aspNet5Runtime "CLR" --aspNet5Architecture "x86"'.
Project file path: .\project.json
Generating deployment script for ASP.NET 5 Application
Generated deployment script files
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET 5 Web Application deployment.
Downloading dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-final from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
Unable to download package: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
At C:\Program Files 
(x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\50.41223.1987\bin\scripts\dnvm.ps1:694 char:13
+             throw "Unable to download package: {0}" -f 
$Global:downloadData.Erro ...
+             
Failed exitCode=1, command=PowerShell -NoProfile -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ''; [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = '';$CmdPathFile='"D:\local\UserProfile\.dnx\temp-set-envvars.cmd"';& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\50.41223.1987\bin\scripts\dnvm.ps1' " install 1.0.0-rc1-final -arch x86 -r CLR
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Unable to downl...Client requ 
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
   est.:String) [], RuntimeException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Unable to download package: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about the repo you're using, but may be better off starting with the [Sample](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/tree/dev/samples/latest) from the dev team. Given dnx is only in RC, a missed change between your clr and the project can cause terrible complications (and at least the aspnet/Home repo is sure to be updated).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Brad. I simply followed the "Install asp.net on linux" guide (http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-linux.html) which told me to install dnx.

The code in my project was created via `yo aspnet`. I have not edited a single line of code.

I do not know how I should compile/launch the Sample from the dev team without dnx..

Comment: The yeoman generators, to my knowledge, haven't been updated in a bit. My understanding, based on the aspnet/announcements repo was that they were focusing efforts on the product. More the reason to start with the sample project; at least that's staying synchronized with the clr changes.

Comment: Btw, for reference, https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/102 they're focusing on visual studio scaffolding over command line (yeoman) as of two months (and a couple of releases) ago

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information Brad. Even though i got my site to work, I would like to follow your advice. The problem is I don't know how to run locally or in Azure (Im super beginner..), is there any guide on how to do that?

Comment: Sorry Brad, just found the guide in the home page of the repo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are hitting not enough disk space issue.
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1682

I tried your code, and repro the deployment failure.

when navigate to https://{site name}.scm.azurewebsites.net, i see below message

`Parser Error Message: There is not enough space on the disk.`

by default free site has 1 GB of disk space, but seems like it is an known issue that asp.net 5 application kind of require a lots of dependency and easily go over the limit. And they (Asp.net 5 folks) are working on addressing the issue.

walk-around is to deploy to a Basic or Standard site

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem! I am using B1 now and my site is up :D